# Let $(G, \cdot)$ be an abelian group, and $g, h\in G$ have orders $a$ and $b$ respectively. What can you say about $(gh)^{ax_0}$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $a, b\in\mathbb Z$, and assume that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
>
> a) Show that there exist $x_0$, $y_0\in\mathbb Z$ such that $ax_0 + by_0 = 1$.
>
> b) Suppose $m\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\mid bm$. Show that $a\mid m$. (Hint: multiply the equation in part (a) by the number $m$.)
>
> c) Unrelated to part (b): suppose $(G, \cdot)$ is an abelian group, and $g, h\in G$ have orders $a$ and $b$ respectively. What can you say about $(gh)^{ax_0}$ ? Where did you use commutativity?

I solved parts a) and b), and here is my attempt for part c):

$g^a = 1$ and $h^b = 1$ since $g, h\in G$ have orders $a$ and $b$ respectively.

$$\begin{align}(gh)^{ax_0} &= (gh)(gh)\cdots(gh) \\&= (gg\cdots g).(hh\cdots h) \\&= g^{ax_0}.h^{ax_0} \\&= (g^a)^{x_0}\cdot h^{1-by_0} \\&=1\cdot h\cdot h^{-by_0} \\&= 1\cdot h\cdot (h^b)^{-y_0} \\&= 1\cdot h\cdot 1 \\&= h\end{align}$$ (since G is commutative)

Is this correct? and if so, what does this result tell me, i.e. what can I say about $(gh)^{ax_0}=h$?

Comment: *NB:* Use `$\in$` for $\in$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct, and you used the commutativity at the equality indicated

$$\begin{align}(gh)^{ax_0} &= (gh)(gh)\cdots(gh) \\&\color{red}{\stackrel{\text{here}}{=}}(gg\cdots g).(hh\cdots h) \\&= g^{ax_0}.h^{ax_0} \\&= (g^a)^{x_0}\cdot h^{1-by_0} \\&=1\cdot h\cdot h^{-by_0} \\&= 1\cdot h\cdot (h^b)^{-y_0} \\&= 1\cdot h\cdot 1 \\&= h.\end{align}$$

> [W]hat can I say about $(gh)^{ax_0}= h$?

One can say that one can cancel the $h$ on the right to get $$(gh)^{ax_0-1}\cdot g=e_G.$$ However, your question is somewhat open-ended, so it's difficult to answer with sufficient accuracy.

Comment: And what does this cancellation tell me? That $(gh) ^{ax_0-1}.g = (gh) ^{ax_0} = e$ and so the order of $(gh) $ is $ax_0$?

Comment: No, @JOJO, but it does tell us that $$g^{-1}=(gh)^{ax_0-1}.$$

Comment: Note, @JOJO, that $$(gh)^{ax_0-1}\cdot g\neq (gh)^{ax_0}.$$